# Relation between 2 tables with a link table

Tags: laravel, orm, relational-database, laravel-5.4

I have this tables :

```
topics
-------
id    |   title
------+----------
1     |   Sport
2     |   Social

posts_topics
------------
id    |   post_id    |   topic_id
------+--------------+------------
1     |    1         |     1
2     |    1         |     2

posts
------
id   |   title
-----+----------
1    |   A Test Post
```

I store topics in `topics` table and use `posts_topics` to link between my `posts` table and `topics`

now I want select `title` of topics when selecting posts,

After some searching in StackOverflow and Google, I've written this models:

**Posts.php**

```
public function post_topics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostTopics');
    }
```

**PostTopics.php**

```
public function topics()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Posts', 'App\Topics', 'id', 'topic_id');

    }
```

**Topics.php**

```
protected $table = 'topics';
```

and in my controller I trying to fetch:

```
$post = Posts::with('post_topics')->find($post_id);
dd($post);
```

Now this code will work but cannot return title of topics.

Comment: You have a many-to-many relationship, with `posts_topics` as the pivot table. You can read up on this here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to a Many to Many relationship in Posts.php:

```
public function post_topics()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Topics', 'posts_topics', 'post_id', 'topic_id');
}
```

And then call it:

```
$post = Posts::with('post_topics')->find($post_id);
```

Try this and check if it works for you.